# Best Way To Make Responsive UI Buttons in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, events

[image]I've been stuck on this for quite some time. I'm trying to make a platformer game for android so I need some touch buttons. I made some buttons in Photoshop but I can't figure out how to make them move the player right. I've tried implementing the `IPointerDownHandler` interface but once I get the player moving I can't stop it, even if I call a function in `OnPointerUp` to set the players velocity to a new vector3 where all values are zero. I've also tried attaching event triggers to the  buttons I made, but it's the opposite the player only moves for one frame and then I have to press the button again. I don't want to import any assets from the asset store and I don't want to use gui system. I want to learn how to do it myself. Thanks in advance. Here is the script in which I call functions from my PlayerController.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class LeftButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{   
    public Image leftButton;

    private PlayerController player;

    private void Start()
    {
        leftButton = GetComponent<Image> ();
        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController> ();
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        Debug.Log("LeftButton Pressed!!");
        player.moveLeft (-2);
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        player.stopMoving ();
        Debug.Log ("Button Lifted!!");
    }
}
```

Here is my PlayerController script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody2D myrb;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        myrb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }

    public void moveLeft(float moveSpeed)
    {
        myrb.velocity = new Vector3 (moveSpeed, myrb.velocity.y, 0f);
    }

    public void moveRight(float moveSpeed)
    {
        myrb.velocity = new Vector3 (moveSpeed, myrb.velocity.y, 0f);
    }

    public void stopMoving()
    {
        myrb.velocity = new Vector3 (0f, 0f, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code you've written?

Comment: Can you show us your PlayerController class too?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by adding two `Event Trigger` with the UI buttons. One calls a public method for `PointerEnter`. Another calls a public method for `PointerExit`.

In the `PointerEnter` trigger call the method that moves the object and in the `PointerExit` trigger call the method that stops the movement.

[image: Base event]

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it. I'll try it and see if it works.

Comment: @DMGregory I've added the PlayerController script.

Comment: I tried your method but I still can't stop it from moving once it starts.

Comment: Have you assigned the objects and selected the methods correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I've posted my code you can look it over if you want.

Comment: [Go through this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-EventTrigger.html) . You have to assign(Drag and drop or delegate) the character script holding object in `None(Object)` field. Then select the intended method from `No Function` dropdown.

Comment: I think I've done that. I attached the Player controller to the player game object, and then drug it into the None(Object) field. Then selected the appropriate function, it does work, just not the way I want it to. When I click or touch the button, the player moves it just wont stop moving even though the stopMoving(); function is called in the OnPointerExit or OnPointerUp event.

Comment: Upload the inspector screenshot selecting any of the buttons.

Comment: I've added the screen shot.